# Where exactly to put the code of Push notification plugin in js file?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification, pushbots

I have added push plugin in my Cordova application from CLI and also edited the code in JS file. But the device( an emulator of android-23) isn't showing any notification when I run the project.

I have followed exactly what is said in this article:http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

But as per this article after running the project the alert will pop up and the device will get registered which isn't happening in my case!

I don't know exactly where to add the code given int the Part2 of the above article.

Below is my JS file:

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.register(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler,{"senderID":"104994837642","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});
},// result contains any message sent from the plugin call
successHandler: function(result) {
    alert('Callback Success! Result = '+result)
},
errorHandler:function(error) {
    alert(error);
},
onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                    alert('registration id = '+e.regid);
                }
            break;

            case 'message':
              // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
              alert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt);
            break;

            case 'error':
              alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
            break;

            default:
              alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
              break;
        }
    }

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Please tell me if I have done correctly or not. If not please guide me through this. Is there any other code I have to include other than this?

**Note:** I have tried third party application called pushbots but there my device is not showing up in the dashboard. Also, if there is any step by step guide for Cordova push notification installation please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM" should be "ecb":"onNotificationGCM" where onNotificationGCM is the name of this function :

```
 onNotificationGCM: function(e) {

 }
```